# Faster way of handling v8 Arrays in Node.js C++ Addon?

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, node.js, node.js-addon

I am working on a Node.js addon/JavaScript codec that utilizes a C based library to handle the encoding/decoding. The addon is quite fast, except in one facet. Currently, decoding arrays takes significantly longer than other implementations (e.g. `JSON.parse` and `MessagePack.decode` ). The method I'm currently using is as follows:

```
Create v8 Local<Array> result;
for (i = 0 to #elements in encoded array)
    result->Set(i, decode(element));
```

The problem is `Set` takes quite a while, so if anyone knows a quicker way for me to do this, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: How many elements are we talking about here?

Comment: @mscdex It could be many. I should clarify, the encoded array originates as a `JavaScript array`. So the user could have passed in an array of 3 elements to be encoded, or 10000. That is stored as an `ArrayBuffer` that is returned to the JS program. The `ArrayBuffer` can then be passed back into the addon for decoding, where conversions happen to break it into the elements (this is part of the C library, not my implementation directly). All I am responsible for is calling the C library to decode each element, and returning an equivalent JS array that represents the one originally encoded.